# "Module not found" errors when using KNEX.js with Quasar Framework (Electron mode)

Tags: electron, vuejs3, knex.js, quasar-framework

I am trying to connect Electron desktop app to **Sqlite** Database via **knex.js**

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
    
    const knex = require('knex')({
      client: 'sqlite3',
      connection: {
        filename: 'src/db/sample.db'
      }
    });
    
    export default boot(async ({ app } ) => {
    
      app.config.globalProperties.$knex = knex
    })
    
    
    export { knex }
```

But, there is multiple errors on compiling like below

**App •  ERROR  •  UI  in** ./node_modules/knex/lib/builder-interface-augmenter.js

Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "util"

*Did you forget to install it?* You can run: `npm install --save util`

- Quasar v2.0.0
- Knex.js v0.95.15
- Vue 3
- sqlite3 v5.0.2